# What is the fastest way to retrieve values from String?

Tags: java, performance

During my app development one performance question came to my mind:

I have a lot of lines of data that can looks like that:

- !ANG:-0.03,0.14,55.31
- !ANG:-0.03,-0.14,305.31
- !ANG:-234.03,-0.14,55.31
- in general: !ANG:float,float,float

Between those lines there are also "damaged" lines - they don't start with ! or are too short/have extra signs and so on.

To detect lines that are damaged at the begining I simply use

```
if(myString.charAt(0) != '!')//wrong string
```

What I can do to detect lines that are damaged at the end? It is very important to mention that I need not only to check if the line is correct but also get those 3 float numbers to use it later.

I've found three options for this:

- use regexp
- split twice (first ":" and second ",") and count elements
- use Scanner class

I am not sure which one of this (or maybe there are other) methods will be the best from the performance point of view. Can you please give me some advice?

**EDIT:**

After some comments I see that it is worth to write how damage lines an look:

- NG:-0.03,0.14,55.31
- .14,55.31
- !ANG:-0.03,0.14,
- !A,-0.02,-0.14,554,-0.12,55

It is quite difficult to talk about number of lines because I am getting them from readings from other device so I get packets of around 20 lines at a time with a frequency of 50Hz.

What I've found out so far is the big drawback of using scanner - for each line I need to create new object and after some time my device is starting to get short on resources.

Comment: Try your three options and find out which is best

Comment: what do you mean by damage at the end?? give a sample damage strings

Comment: All these options will works but the answer here depends on your "undamaged"  lines too, so can you post some ?

Comment: How many is a lot? Unless you have billions of these lines it is unlikely to matter which technique you use.

Comment: These damaged lines looks like you're concurrently writing the file from multiple threads/processes without proper synchronization. You should fix your producing programs first.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark them, then you will know.

The likely fastest way is to write your own tiny state machine to match your format and find the float boundaries. *Theoretically* a regex will have the same performance, but it's likely to have additional overhead.

Comment: Agreed. *Theoretically* a regex will have the same performance as a state machine, but [in practice most regex implementations don't](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). Note too that "a state machine to match your format" is usually called a [Lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate solution I'd do something like that :

```
private static class LineObject {
    private float f1, f2, f3;
}

private LineObject parseLine(String line) {
    LineObject obj = null;
    if (line.startsWith("!ANG:")) {
        int i = line.indexOf(',', 5);
        if (i != -1) {
            int j = line.indexOf(',', i+1);
            if (j != -1) {
                try {
                    obj = new LineObject();
                    obj.f1 = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(5, i));
                    obj.f2 = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(i+1, j));
                    obj.f3 = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(++j));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

After you can copy/paste only usefull jdk code of startsWith, indexOf and parseFloat in your own state machine...